# whats the best way to use tags in aspx

Tags: asp.net, html

I'd lke to know the best way to use tags in html, using asp tags or using normal html tags.

this:

```
<asp:Button ID="save" runat="server" Text="Save" />
```

or this:

```
<input type="button" id="save" runat="server" value="Save" />
```

Advantages and Disadvantages

Comment: Advantage: The software sees a control, which can be handled/manipulated/whatnot and so forth. Disadvantage: The software sees a control which much be handled/manipulated/whatnot and oh god, it must be wrangled with before being output'd. So it depends.

Comment: I agree with Jared. It depends. We just add runat="server" to a regular HTML tag to make ASP.Net aware of it. In our practice, we prefer using ASP.NET tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use asp tags ,especially in case of buttons i will  prefer to use asp tags, Because when you use a html tag for button with `runat="server"` the attributes like `PostBackUrl` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

They're just the same. The other one is the so-called server tag or ASP tag and the other one is HTML tag. It's just a matter of style and preference.

Now, if you want to know what is the preferred tags used by ASP.Net developers, I'm sure most of us would agree that it's ASP tags. Well, at least for the ASP.Net Webform developers...